# ComboBox - how to prevent selecting item after dropped down

Tags: c#, winforms

If I am typing for example "q" and there is item in combobox items which first letter is "q" then after dropping down it jumps to this item. Is there any way to prevent this for typing more letters?

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the key was to replace the event to TextUpdate and replace text after dropdown and then deselect text in ComboBox.

```
    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var savedText = comboBox1.Text;
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        comboBox1.Text = savedText;
        comboBox1.Select(savedText.Length, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Comment: +1. This is the answer you're after OP. Done this recently myself.

Comment: Actually I cant'use AutoComplete for some reasons an I use my own search provider (I skip it in my code example).